# How to include multiple style sections in web component

Tags: web-component, native-web-component

I have style sections being added in sub-classes.

Very simplified version:

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.html = `
            <style>
                :host {
                    /* some css in here */
                }
            </style>
            <style>
                :host {
                    /* additional css in here */
                }
            </style>`
    }
//...
}
```

The second style section seems to be getting ignored.

Should this work OK?

Update: It works if the style section isn't split

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.html = `
            <style>
                :host {
                    /* some css in here */
                    /* additional css in here */
                }
            </style>`
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: Yes, valid. What is the CSS that isn't applied? Make an SO snippet, Ctrl-M when you are writing a question

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman See update. Remove the break in the style and works ok - so something is fishy. Re SO snippet etc: Real Soon Now! (is that still a thing?)

Comment: Nailed it. The structure is fine. Thanks. The problem was further along when adding/removing children: Allowed only for the first node being a style element.